# How can I save the current tig options into a file

Tags: tig

I've made several modifications manually in tig, and I want to store them.

How can I save the current set of changed tig options into a file (the ones, that I can toggle using the (o) key in tig) ?

(I know about .tigrc, so if there is a way to force tig to dump the current settings into its .tigrc file, I guess it will suffice ...)

Comment: This is not currently possible, but would be a helpful thing for testing so I will create an issue for it.

Comment: See https://github.com/jonas/tig/issues/315

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of version 2.1 of `tig` this can now be done from within `tig` by typing `:` to get into the command mode and then `save-options <filename>`.

All options are then dumped to the named file regardless of their state in any of the configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

With Tig 2.5.4, the
`:save-options` runtime command saves to "tig-options.txt" in current directory by default, or you can specify `:save-options ~/.tigrc` to have it saved into the global configuration.

I did run into an error

```
  tig
tig warning: ~/.tigrc:26: Value must be between 0 and 1024
tig warning: Errors while loading /c/Users/user/.tigrc.
```

There was some random option (forget name) that was -50, which caused validation failure. I had to remove that part manually.

`set main-view                 = line-number:no,interval=5 id:yes,color=no date:relative-compact,local=no,format= author:abbreviated commit-title:yes,graph=v2,refs=yes,xyz=-50`

Comment: Read answers to a post you want to answer to before. It's already been answered 7 years before yours that you can directly save them to the tigrc without doing it by hand like you are showing and falsely implying it is needed.

Comment: I think I did that intentionally to validate the config before overriding my .TigRC, but point taken and updated the answer to reflect your good advice.